# String method output not understanding

Tags: java

From the below question I din't understand how the output has come. Could someone please explain me how did it come ?

```
public class mystery{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(serios("DELIVER"));

}



public static String serios(String s)
{
     String s1 = s.substring(0,1);
     System.out.println(s1);
     String s2 = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);
     System.out.println(s2);
     String s3 = s.substring(s.length() - 1);
     System.out.println(s3);
     if (s.length() <= 3)
          return s3 + s2 + s1;

     else
          return s1 + serios(s2) + s3;
}
}
```

Output:

```
D
ELIVE
R
E
LIV
E
L
I
V
DEVILER
```

Thanks !!

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm).

Comment: Please, you should read the documentation and try to understand the output before asking your question.

Comment: Additionally, there's a recursive call to `serios()`.  You may see what's going on, if you use the debugging features of your IDE, set breakpoints and watch the variables.

Comment: Which part of the code/output do you not understand? E.g. do you understand why the first line is a `D`? If not, then read the link @Gendarme provided.

Comment: A common approach for understanding a recursive method it to trace its method calls.  See my answer

Answer (score 0):

For this chunk of code

```
     String s1 = s.substring(0,1);//this initializes s1 = D as Substring reads up to right before the ending index which is 1.
     System.out.println(s1);//print s1
```

This chunk

```
     String s2 = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);//Starts where the previous chunk left off, ends right before the ending initializing s2 = ELIVE
     System.out.println(s2);//print s2
```

Final Chunk

```
     String s3 = s.substring(s.length() - 1);//This chunk starts from the end and captures R
     System.out.println(s3);//print s3
```

These three chunks and their print statements will give you

```
D ELIVE R
```

Now let's move on.

The final return statement returns `s1 + serios(s2) + s3`. **This is recursion, a function called within itself.**

This recursion will run until the if condition is met. Finally printing out `DELIVER`

You can see a pattern to understand better.

`DELIVER` when run through the code is printed out like this `D ELIVE R`. The first and last letters are separated from the center of the word.

```
return s1 + serios(s2) + s3;
```

since `s2 = ELIVE` it will become equal to `s`. It will be split apart using substring just like `DELIVER` to become `E LIV E` setting

```
LIV = s2
```

`s` will now equal `LIV`, and be split apart and printed out as

```
L I V
```

Finally the length of `s` is equal to 3, so the if condition will run and print out `DEVILER`

Answer (score 0):

apart of what subString is doing, I think your problem is about recursive behavior of the series method.

at first call u send "DELIVER".

at the following line you can see if the input param is grater than 3 the method call itself agin this time with s2. for the first iteration **s2 =  ELIVE**.

```
if (s.length() <= 3)
      return s3 + s2 + s1;

 else
      return s1 + serios(s2) + s3;
```

you can think about running series("ELIVE"); and for the same process you will see this time s2 will get "LIV" which the recursion do not happen again and if part will run.

```
 if (s.length() <= 3)
          return s3 + s2 + s1;
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of tasks, it helps to **trace** the method calls

```
public class mystery {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        serios("DELIVER", "");
    }

    public static String serios(String s, String indentation)
    {
        String s1 = s.substring(0, 1);
        System.out.println(indentation + "\"" + s1 + "\" is the substring of \"" + s + "\" at 0");

        String s2 = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);
        System.out.println(indentation + "\"" +s2 + "\" is the substring of \"" + s + "\" from 1 to " + (s.length() - 2));

        String s3 = s.substring(s.length() - 1);
        System.out.println(indentation + "\"" + s3 + "\" is the substring of \"" + s + "\" at " + (s.length() - 1));

        if (s.length() <= 3)
            return s3 + s2 + s1;
        else 
        {
            indentation += " ";
            return s1 + serios(s2, indentation) + s3;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Output:**

```
"D" is the substring of "DELIVER" at 0
"ELIVE" is the substring of "DELIVER" from 1 to 5
"R" is the substring of "DELIVER" at 6
 "E" is the substring of "ELIVE" at 0
 "LIV" is the substring of "ELIVE" from 1 to 3
 "E" is the substring of "ELIVE" at 4
  "L" is the substring of "LIV" at 0
  "I" is the substring of "LIV" from 1 to 1
  "V" is the substring of "LIV" at 2
```